# Machine readable, user non-readable - XML file

Tags: encryption

I need some advice as I have been unable to find anything useful via the web - (Google search).

I have used the application EventGhost so as to create a custom shell, that I run using the Windows 7 Professional OS as an alternative to the explorer shell. I was wondering what options I have (and even if it is actually possible), so as to encrypt the resultant XML code, so that it appears as gibberish to the end user, but remains as readable to the system (and most importantly the eventghost application).

Comment: IMO, the best persons to ask this, are the software developers of EventGhost. Sorry, I don't think this is by any means related to topics covered here.

Answer (score 4):

What you are talking about is not so much encryption as obfuscation. Obfuscation techniques are generally not considered part of cryptography.

XML is a data format and as such doesn't perform any processing by itself. Obviously it can contain elements that require processing but that processing is probably not Turing complete. That means that an encrypted XML file by itself cannot be interpreted by the EventGhost parser. Besides that, EventGhost can probably not be configured with a key, so that makes it impossible to use symmetric or asymmetric encryption techniques.

So what can you do with regards to obfuscation? Well, you can replace all the readable characters within the tags by escape codes. See [the W3 XML specifications for more detail](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn). But please don't call this cryptography or encryption. Google for XML obfuscation and you may find other resources.

If you want real crypto then you must be able to decrypt before the XML file is processed. [XML-enc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html) would of course come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem by creating a new user on your system which will be used to launch eventghost.

You could then login to your system an encrypt the eventghost configuration by enabling to check box (file property dialog -> Advanced -> Encrypt contents to secure data).

Change your security attributes accordingly. Then log into your system with your normal account and launch eventghost under the newly created user. Eventghost *will* be able to read to file, while others will not be able to do so.